# Net Use Command will not work on COM ports (they do on LPT ports)

Tags: cmd.exe

Currently I am logged in as the Administrator user in elevated command prompt and I run the following command which fails.

*net use COM3: \TEST-SVR\generic1*

Response:
*System error 66 has occured.
The network resource type is not correct.*

Though, if I test this with an LPT port with the following request.

*use net LPT3: \TEST-SVR\generic1*

Reponse:
*The command completed successfully.*

LPT ports work, though COM ports do not.  I've been exploring ways to enable COM ports though I haven't had luck so far.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: "I've been exploring ways to enable COM ports" What do you want to do with the com port?

Comment: I have an application that sends a command (open cash drawer) via COM port.  Modern hardware connection is via USB so I need to redirect the COM command to the USB peripheral.